# Error: Incompatible SOCKS protocol version: 71

Tags: node.js, ssh, module, socks

I am trying to implement the ssh2 node module example which is using socksv5.

```
var socks = require('socksv5'),
Connection = require('ssh2');

var ssh_config = {
host: '192.168.100.1',
port: 22,
username: 'nodejs',
password: 'rules'
};

socks.createServer(function(info, accept, deny) {
var conn = new Connection();
conn.on('ready', function() {
   conn.forwardOut(info.srcAddr,
                   info.srcPort,
                   info.dstAddr,
                   info.dstPort,
                   function(err, stream) {
                      if (err)
                         return deny();

                     var clientSocket;
                     if (clientSocket = accept(true)) {
                        stream.pipe(clientSocket).pipe(stream).on('close', function() {
                        conn.end();
                        });
                     } else
                         conn.end();
                  });
              }).on('error', function(err) {
                   deny();
          }).connect(ssh_config);
       }).listen(1080, 'localhost', function() {
            console.log('SOCKSv5 proxy server started on port 1080');
       }).useAuth(socks.auth.None());
```

ssh2 connection is working but I am getting this error when calling the page in browser.

Help would be much appreciated
Kind regards Thomas

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to use the SOCKS 5 proxy as an HTTP proxy. These are not the same protocols.

So for example in Firefox, Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Connection Settings -> "SOCKS Host" is what you want to fill out (localhost and port 1080), not "HTTP Proxy."

Comment: Do you think this is then the best way to accomplish what i am doing? I am trying to render a homepage behind an ssh server in a site on my homepage. So I have a homepage running on a webserver on a raspberry pi and another homepage hosted at heroku. What I am trying to do is to connect via ssh to the raspberry pi and render its homepage on the one hosted by heroku. Thanks again for your help.